# Passing controllers to angularjs components

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to implement this behavior using AngularJS components.

```
<parent-component>
   <reusable-child-component></reusable-child-component>
</parent-component>
```

What I want is to pass the parent's controller to the a reusable child component. I know that passing controllers can be done using require attribute but will include the name of the parent's component. (ex. require : '^parentComponent').

Is it possible for me to pass dynamic controller to the child component? That the child component will dynamically receive whatever its parent controller.

```
<parent-component>
   <reusable-child-component></reusable-child-component>
</parent-component>


<parent2-component>
   <reusable-child-component></reusable-child-component>
</parent2-component>
```

Need suggestions or help. If possible, written in typescript.

Comment: Why do you need this and why can't you simply use bindings for this purpose? This is not a good idea but you can try to use [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/aygqcgeb/10/).

Answer (score 1):

Just use a binding on the child component like so:

```
<reusable-child-component my-data="dataFromParentController"></reusable-child-component>
```

Look at the official documentation for components -
 https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component